# htaccess mod rewrite confusion

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to apply mod rewrites to my URL to make it nicer but I am getting caught up in all the confusion of this subject.

Please could you help me out with the following examples of what I want to do :

I want to attach any variable from the root of my site into the lyprofile.php page

```
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /(.*)
RewriteRule /(.*) lyprofile.php?us=$1
```

I want a url such as profile/settings to go to lysettings.php

```
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /profile/settings
RewriteRule /profile/settings lysettings.php
```

These two examples if working should help me to work out all my other URL's, but I can't get these to work.

Also do you need an absolute URL, as I'm working on my local machine and an absolute URL would just cause a lot of hassle. Just in case my absolute URL is `http://localhost/Linku2.5/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You generally want to go from the most specific rules to the least specific. Of the two things that you want to do, the first is the least specific, as `(.*)` can be *anything*. So we have to start with the much more specific and less arbitrary `/profile/settings`.

If these rules are in your htaccess file (in your case, in the `Link2.5` directory), you don't want a leading slash, so simply:

```
# you only need to turn on once
RewriteEngine On

# Don't need absolute URLs, but you may need this line:
RewriteBase /Link2.5/

RewriteRule ^profile/settings lysettings.php [L]
```

Then, because your other rule is so general, you need to add some conditions so that you don't cause an infinite loop (the rewrite engine will continue to loop until the URI stops changing):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ lyprofile.php?us=$1 [L,QSA]
```

If you know your "us" variable can only be numbers or letters, you can make the line with the rule a bit more specific:

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9]+)$ lyprofile.php?us=$1 [L,QSA]
```

etc.

Comment: I've tried this over and over and it just says that the url can't be found; what I am doing wrong!

Comment: @JackTrowbridge Make sure everything is in the right place, make sure mod_rewrite is turned on, make sure your htaccess files are being read, make sure you can access the targets (e.g. lysettings.php and lyprofile.php), check your error logs,

Comment: I have, but there is also another problem that I think renders this method useless for me. When I did having it working with other code as say for example I had the url "profile/settings" which redirected to lysettings.php; the problem is within lysettings.php it acts like it has the url profile/settings, so all style sheets and links are not found as they are referenced from root; it doesn't redirect it basically acts as the url? Is this normal?

Comment: @JackTrowbridge "**it doesn't redirect it basically acts as the url? Is this normal?**" that's what "rewriting" is, it's entirely on the server's end, it's different from "redirect" this is what mod_*rewrite* is made to do. As for the css stuff, you've got relative URIs in your content, change them all to absolute or add a `<base href="/Link2.5/">` or whatever in the page's header

Answer (score 0):

Can you check this in vhosts config?

```
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule lyprofile\.php - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /(.*)
RewriteRule /(.*) lyprofile.php?us=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /profile/settings
RewriteRule /profile/settings lysettings.php [L]
```